# How to assign a single output to different modules in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, output, module

I have designed a simple ALU using Floating Point IP Cores in Xilinx ISE. I have an adder, a subtractor, and a multiplier. The IP Core of addition does the subtraction too and we have only two modules of addition and multiplication.

Inputs and outputs for each module is as following:

Inputs: a, b, clk, ce

Outputs: result, overflow, underflow, invalid_op, rdy

I want to connect the outputs of the modules to the outputs of the top module ALU (e.g [8:0] result of ALU to the result outputs of the two modules). How can I do this?

Here is the code:

```
module ALU( a, b, select, clock, 
            underflow, overflow, invalid_op, ready, result );

//inputs
input  clock;
input  [8:0] a;
input  [8:0] b;
input  [1:0] select;

//outputs
output underflow;
output overflow;
output invalid_op;
output ready;
output [8:0] result;

//registers
reg rdy;
reg [1:0] ce;

//wires
wire [8:0] b_input; 

//for subtraction it makes the second input negative.
assign b_input = {select[0],b[7:0]};

//choose which block to be used
always @(posedge clock)
begin
    case(select)
        2'b 00:
            ce <= 2'b 01;
        2'b 01:
            ce <= 2'b 01;
        2'b 10:
            ce <= 2'b 10;
        2'b 11:
            ce <= 2'b xx;
        default:
            ce <= 2'b xx;
    endcase
end


FPAdd add_or_subtract_ipcore (
                                          .a(a), // input [8 : 0] a
                                          .b(b_input), // input [8 : 0] b
                                          .clk(clock), // input clk
                                          .ce(ce[0]), // input ce
                                          .result(result), // output [8 : 0] result
                                          .underflow(underflow), // output underflow
                                          .overflow(overflow), // output overflow
                                          .invalid_op(invalid_op), // output invalid_op
                                          .rdy(ready) // output rdy
                                        );

FPMult      multiply_ipcore  (
                                          .a(a), // input [8 : 0] a
                                          .b(b), // input [8 : 0] b
                                          .clk(clock), // input clk
                                          .ce(ce[1]), // input ce
                                          .result(result), // output [8 : 0] result
                                          .underflow(underflow), // output underflow
                                          .overflow(overflow), // output overflow
                                          .invalid_op(invalid_op), // output invalid_op
                                          .rdy(ready) // output rdy
                                        );
```

endmodule

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you need "multiplexer", think "case statement". You already have a `case` statement — so do your output assignment there, too.

You'll need to create a separate bus for the output of each of your IP cores — `result_add`, `result_mult`, etc.